# AND OR filter in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, garb-gem

I have a question: how do i write 2 conditions in filters params? `:page_path.eql => "/teams/1" or :page_path.eql => 'teams/2'`

it works for one condition, but dont work with two:(

```
output = Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.eql => "/teams/1"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
output = Exits.results(profile,:filters =>{:page_path.contains => "^/teams/[1|2]$"})
```

you can also try shorthand

```
output = profile.exits(:filters =>{:page_path.contains => "^/teams/[1|2]$"})
```

with date options

```
output = Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.contains => "^/teams/[1|2]$"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)
```

or

```
output = profile.exits(:filters => {:page_path.contains => "^/teams/[1|2]$"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)
```

This works for me

use `contains` instead of `matches` I think it does not understand regex.

Comment: It isn't work! I was try `output = Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.matches => "/admin/teams/1", 
"/admin/teams/23"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)``output = Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.matches => "/admin/teams/#{'1'||'23'}"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)
``output = Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.matches => "/admin/teams/#{'1','2'}"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)
` and your idea but nothing matches

Comment: @TranduyKhoa ,use contains instead of matches I think it does not understand regex.

check updated answer

Comment: what output for this `profile.exits(:filters => {:page_path.contains => "/admin/teams/[1|2]"},:start_date => Date.new(2012,8,13),:end_date => Date.today)`

Comment: #<Garb::ResultSet:0x007f9730512600 @results=[#<OpenStruct **page_path="/admin/teams/1** page_path="/admin/teams/1" **page_path="/admin/teams/2**", date="20120817">, #<OpenStruct page_path="/admin/teams/2/transactions/viewers"page_path="/admin/teams/2/transactions/viewers" #page_path="/admin/teams/23/viewers page_path="/admin/teams/2/views"
it worked in this case, but when i changed to _matches_, -> no result. I wanna make a query to get `team/1 and /2 only`! Any way, thanks for your help:)

Comment: @TranduyKhoa I got waht you want I have updated answer hope that helps. use regex "^query$" to limit out search